# What's causing the shrinkwrap artifcting on my model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing, artifacts, retopology

I'm trying to retopologise a very messy and destructively created mesh that was non manifold. However, after giving it a shrinkwrap and subdivision modifier, I'm noticing some strange indents that were not present in the original mesh. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image: I'm trying to retopologise a very messy and destructively created mesh that was non manifold. However, after giving it a shrinkwrap and subdivision modifier, I'm noticing some strange indents that were not present in the original mesh. Does anyone know why this is happening?]

[image: Here is the model in edit mode to show what the mesh looks like]

Comment: It's not very clear from the images what mesh you are remeshing and how and what exactly you want to achieve. Could you edit the question and clarify?

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stack exchange, so I'm not really familiar with the UI. Should I just add a new image onto my original post to show what I'm trying to shrinkwrap?